# Untoiveled but used dinnerware and cookware - how to salvage if possible?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, tevilas-keilim-dipping

What's the deal with untoiveled, but used, dinnerware and cookware? Can they still be toiveled to make usable/kosher or must it all be tossed?

Comment: You should distinguish in the question between dishes, pots, etc that are kosher but have not undergone tevilah and those that have been made "not kosher".

Comment: Sorry, I was only referring to those only used for kosher cooking, but have not undergone tevilah.